# What is the purpose of "<<" (double less than) in groovy

Tags: groovy

I saw in some of the code which I am unable to understand the purpose of << like in the following sample code

```
def renderFiles(args) {
   def model = []
   args.each { fileArgs ->
      model << createModel(fileArgs.id,fileArgs.path,fileArgs.ext)
   }
   render view:'show', model: [files:model]
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a `leftShift` operator. In groovy operator overloading is implemented, see [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) and [**the new docs**](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html) for reference . In this particular case adding an element to list operation is overloaded.

Instead of:

`model.add(createModel(fileArgs.id,fileArgs.path,fileArgs.ext))`

You can simply write:

`model << createModel(fileArgs.id,fileArgs.path,fileArgs.ext)`

It's a kind of a shorthand. There are also other operators overridden for List class, e.g. `plus()`, `minus()`. See [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 8):

In groovy `<<` operator adds result of expression on the right side to the collection on the left side