# What's the operator << (double less than) in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

The following piece of code defines 4 gradle tasks:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" << {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

But what is the << operator? What does it do in groovy?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basically this is a `leftShift` operator - You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818951/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-groovy/24819059#24819059).

In gradle `<<` operator is used to add *action* to a particular *task*. A task consists of multiple actions that are run (in order they were added) during the execution of the task. `<<` just adds an action to tasks collection of actions. More about tasks and actions can be found [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html).

Comment: That's in gradle the operator is overloaded to add a task to the action, right?

Comment: A task is just a closure in groovy, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is overloaded in this class exactly: `org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask`. When it comes to the second question, not exactly. A task is always an instance of `DefaultTask` class (or a class that extends `DefaultTask` (it may be defined as a kind of a *closure*, but doesn't have to).

Comment: I've found sources http://www.massapi.com/source/gradle-0.9-rc-3/subprojects/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractTask.java.html where exact that operator overloaded? Could you point me?

Comment: It's very old sourcefile. It's overloaded here: `public Task leftShift(Closure action) {
        return doLast(action);
}` and it's java but gradle's DSL is used with groovy. You can call `doLast()` or `leftShift()` methods instead of using `<<` operator.

Answer (score 56):

The `<<` is a left-shift operator.  In this scenario, `task "task$counter"` is a [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) object declaration, and `<<` is overloaded as an alias to the [`doLast`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:doLast(org.gradle.api.Action)) method, which appends the closure to the list of actions to perform when executing the task.

If you don't specify the `<<`, the closure is treated as a [configuration closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#configureUsingClosure) and will be executed by default during the configuration phase of your project's [build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases), regardless of whatever task argument is given on the command line.

**Example:**

If you take the configuration specified in the question:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" << {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

And run `gradle task3`, the output will be:

```
:task3
I'm task number 3
```

Because each closure was defined to be an execution action specific to the task.  Since `task3` was named as the task to execute, that was the only action closure executed.

But if you remove the `<<` and make the configuration as follows:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" {
        println "I'm task number $counter"
    }
}
```

And run `gradle task3`, the output will then be:

```
I'm task number 0
I'm task number 1
I'm task number 2
I'm task number 3
:task3 UP-TO-DATE
```

This is because all closures were defined to *configure* the tasks themselves, not be executed as actions when running the tasks.  So in this case, Gradle executed all of the closures while configuring the project, then when it came time to *execute* `task3`, there were no actions to perform, so it reported the task as `UP-TO-DATE`.

Comment: This comment saves my day!

Comment: Great explaination @heenenee

Comment: It's good to point that *4-times printing `I'm task number N` in the second situation*, is done in **every task** running. Not just `taskN`s.