# What actually 'gradle -q task' does?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I've written a build script:

```
task hello                       // 1

hello << {                       // 2
            println "task hello"
}

hello << {                       // 3
   println "another task hello"
}
```

As I've understood `//1` defines an object of `Task` type, `//2` and `//3` applies `leftShift(Closure c)` operator to that task. When I ran that script with command `gradle -q hello` I saw the following output:

```
task hello
another task hello
```

Taking that into account can we say that `gradle -q task_name` executes all closure's body to which `operator <<` was applied or the command has another meaning?

Answer (score 8):

`gradle -q hello` sets logging level to *quiet* (`println`s are logged at that level and hence will still be shown) and executes task `hello`. Executing a task means executing all its *task actions*. Your build script adds two task actions, which will be executed in the order they were added. (`<<` is an alias for `doLast`, which adds a task action to the end of a task's list of task actions).

> ```
> # gradle -h
> ...
> -q, --quiet             Log errors only.
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 3):

No, `-q` switch is used to suppress all the messages that are logged to console (except error level) and `print` statement.

If You execute the following script:

```
task lol

lol << {
    println '1' 
}

lol << {
    logger.lifecycle '2'
}
```

without `-q` switch You'll get both `1` and `2` in output. With `-q` switch only `1` will be printed.

`<<` operator is completely different thing - it's used to add `action` to a `task`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085379/whats-the-operator/26085415#26085415) answer for details.