# Why gradle clean task starts all other non-default tasks?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gradle set up and running. My `build.gradle` has 2 tasks defined inside:

```
task setVersion() {
    println('setVersion')
    //...
}

task setIntegrationEnv() {
    println('setIntegrationEnv')
    //...
}
```

When I run

```
./gradlew clean
```

gradle runs both tasks `setVersion` and `setIntegrationEnv` and then it runs clean for all my modules (`app`, `cloud_module`) in that project, output:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
setVersion
setIntegrationEnv
:cloud_module:clean
:app:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.18 secs
```

Why this happens, where this behavior is defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle task should not execute automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could You please provide full `build.gradle` script? I'd be much easier to help You. You've probably mistaken gradle *build* phase with *configuration* phase - it's a common topic here.

General rule is that code You'd like to be run at *build* phase should be added as an *action*:

```
task someTask << {
   println 'runtime'
}
```

while code You'd like to run at *configuration* phase should be added in task body:

```
task someTask  {
   println 'configuration
}
```

or all together:

```
task someTask {
   println 'configuration'

   doLast {
      println 'runtime'
   }
}
```

Additional info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818951/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-groovy/24819059#24819059), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085379/whats-the-operator/26085415#26085415) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546286/gradle-task-should-not-execute-automatically/23546350#23546350).

Comment: I recommend to always use `doLast` instead of `<<`, as using `<<` is very error-prone (easy to forget etc.).

Comment: Marian Paździoch: is that what You're looking fir?

Comment: Yes it is - and I marked is as duplicate of one of those questions you proposed.

Comment: If it is what You're looking for, please accept the answer.