# Jar file not copied in gradle multi module project

Tags: java, jar, gradle

Im using Gradle 2.1
When I run `gradle jar` at root dir, I can get *hoge.jar* in *hoge/distribution*,  but there is no *common.jar* in *distribution/libs*.
If I run `gradle jar` again, `common.jar` is built under *distribution/libs*.

Why *common.jar* doesn't appear in *distribution/libs* at the first time?

setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = "sample"
include "common"
include "hoge"
```

root-> build.gradle

```
allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'idea'
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
}
```

common -> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')
}
```

hoge -> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':common')
   compile('org.dbunit:dbunit:2.2')
}

jar {
   copy {
      from configurations.compile
      into "distribution/lib"
   }
   def manifestClasspath = configurations.compile.collect{ 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
   manifest {
      attributes "Main-Class" : "com.hoge.TestMain"
      attributes 'Class-Path': manifestClasspath
   }
   from (configurations.compile.resolve().collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : fileTree(it) }) {
      exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
   }
   destinationDir = file("distribution")
   archiveName = 'hoge.jar'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all You've mixed logic in `jar` configuration closure. This closure should be responsible only for configuring the jar file being created, *not* for preparing distribution dir also. So this is how the task should look like:

```
jar {
   def manifestClasspath = configurations.compile.collect{ 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
   manifest {
      attributes "Main-Class" : "com.hoge.TestMain"
      attributes 'Class-Path': manifestClasspath
   }
   from (configurations.compile.resolve().collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : fileTree(it) }) {
      exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
      exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
   }
   destinationDir = file("distribution")
   archiveName = 'hoge.jar'
}
```

Then, why the `common.jar` file isn't copied when the jar task is run for the first time? You should know that some parts of task is being executed at *configuration* phase and some at *run*  (for more clarification see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468507/why-gradle-clean-task-starts-all-other-non-default-tasks/26468602#26468602) e.g.). The following part of code:

```
copy {
   from configurations.compile
   into "distribution/lib"
}
```

is run at *configuration* and as stated in the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files): *When an argument resolves to a non-existing file, that argument is ignored.* and this is what happens. `common.jar` doesn't exist yet so it's ignored, hence not copied. When `jar` is run for the second time `common.jar` already exists so it's not resolved to null and copied.

To resolve this problem create a `dist` task:

```
task dist << {
   project.copy {
      from configurations.compile
      into file('distribution/lib')
   }
}
jar.finalizedBy(dist)
```

that finalizes `jar` task and copies all the required artifacts to *distribution* dir. Hope it's clear now.