# Groovy's << operator is confusing

Tags: groovy, bitwise-operators

I'm new to Groovy and I am very lost with respect to the `<<` operator. I understand its use as a bit shifter as follows:

```
def x = 2
x << 2 //x == 8
```

However, the operator has another use when being used in a closure in strings:

```
"${ w -> w << 3}" //w == 3
```

So my question is this: In what situations does `<<` act as an assignment operator? In what situations does it act as a bit shifter?

This second example is really what got me confused:

```
def transform(List elements, Closure action) {                    
    def result = []
    elements.each {
        result << action(it)
    }
    result
}
```

Here it seems that `<<` performs an append. So is there a set of rules on `<<`? Does `<<` behave differently for every data structure? Is there a codified set of rules somewhere? I can't seem to find anything on this in the Groovy documentation; instead, it's casually thrown in, in different examples, which is confusing at best.

Comment: your transform could as well be written as `elements.collect{action(it)}`, which would be less confusing ;)

Comment: Quick rule: Whenever you see `x << y`, think of it as `x.leftShift(y)` Then it's just a matter of understanding the JavaDocs for whatever `x`'s type is.

Comment: I can appreciate why it might be a little confusing, but it really can make sense. Think of the `<<` operator as shorthand for calling the `leftShift` method.  The `leftShift` method may do fundamentally different things in different classes. This is similar to something like invoking the `add` method on a `java.util.ArrayList` vs. invoking the `add` method on a `java.math.BigDecimal`. Those are fundamentally different types and `add` means different things in those 2 contexts.  I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks all for your comments here.  All of these answers were helpful.  It still concerns me that you can do this, but at least your comments seem to shed light on how I should think about it.

Comment: just like the `+` operator has different effect on different types, so does `<<`. e.g. : `1 + 1 // 2`, but `"1" + 1 // "11"`

Answer (score 3):

In Groovy, `<<` is an operator that can be overloaded for various classes, so it has different behavior depending on the context in which it's being used. See [the docs](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/operators.html) and [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818951/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-groovy/24819059#24819059) for more.

In the examples you provided, the code works as follows:

```
def x = 2
assert x << 2 == 8
```

This is plain old bit shift. In the [`DefaultGroovyMethods` class](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java)  (where most *fancy* methods are defined), there's a `leftShift` for `Number` method overloaded which, through [`NumberMath`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/NumberMath.java) and then through [`IntegerMath`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/IntegerMath.java), does the operation.

In the second case:

```
assert "${ w -> w << 3}" == '3'
```

It works similarly except for the fact that the [`IOGroovyMethods`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java) and [`InvokerHelper`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.java) classes are used.

In the last case:

```
def transform(List elements, Closure action) {                    
    def result = []
    elements.each {
        result << action(it)
    }
    result
}
```

The class [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java) is used again.

You can even override operators in a self-defined class:

```
class Lol {
    def leftShift(o) {
        println o
    }
}

new Lol() << 'string' //prints 'string'
```

Comment: the `${w->w<<3}` really puzzled me

Comment: Indeed. I'm still not completely sure what happens there.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is an operator that types may define however they wish:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#Operator-Overloading

Collections, for example, overload `leftShift`, using it as an append operation.